# react change slide in slider after clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a Sidebar that I've implemented this way:

```
import React from "react";
import './MySidebar.scss';
import {slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

export class MySidebar extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


 changeSlide = (e) => {
   console.log("Clicked " + e.currentTarget.id); //get text content of
 }


  render() {


    return (
        <Menu customCrossIcon={false}>
            <button onClick={((e) => this.changeSlide(e))} className ="menu-item" id="Project1">Project 1</button>
      <button onClick={((e) => this.changeSlide(e))} className ="menu-item" id="Project2">Project 2</button>
        </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have a component called `ProjectSliderComponent` that realizes the behaviour of a carousel. It is done this way:

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import './project-carousel.component.css';
import { ProjectComponent } from '../project/project.component';
import { LoggerService } from '../../services/logger-service';
import { appConfig } from '../../config';

export class ProjectSliderComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    activeSlide: 0,
    timestamp: Date.now()
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logger = new LoggerService();

    this.settings = {
      dots: appConfig.dots,
      arrows: false,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      infinite: appConfig.infinite,
      speed: appConfig.speed,
      autoplay: appConfig.autoplay,
      autoplaySpeed: appConfig.autoplaySpeed,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      mobileFirst: true,
      className: 'heliosSlide',
      beforeChange: (current, next) => {
        this.setState({ activeSlide: next, timestamp: Date.now() }); 
      }
    };
  }

  render() {

    let i = 0;

    return (
      <div>
      <Slider ref = {c => (this.slider = c)} {...this.settings}>
        {
          this.props.projectListId.data.map(projectId =>
              <ProjectComponent key={projectId} id={projectId} time={this.state.timestamp} originalIndex={ i++ } currentIndex = {this.state.activeSlide}></ProjectComponent>)
        }
      </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `ProjectComponent` component simply specifies the layout. This is the `App.js` file, where I load the projectslidercomponent and my sidebar. I do this:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    projectList: new ProjectListModel(),
    isLoading: true
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logger = new LoggerService();
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    let projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.getProjectList()
      .then(res => {
        let projectList = new ProjectListModel();
        projectList.data = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ projectList: projectList,
                        isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.logger.error(error);
      });
  }



  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <MySidebar>
            </MySidebar>
          <ProjectSliderComponent projectListId={this.state.projectList}></ProjectSliderComponent>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What I need to do is to change the slide according to which button I clicked. What do I have to do? Is there something like passing the "instance" of the `projectslidercomponent` and call a method to change the slide? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort this problem what you have to do is create a function in parent component which updates the state of the app component and once the state is updated it will re render app component and the new props are send to slider component which will tell which slider to show. Below is the code :-

In App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    projectList: new ProjectListModel(),
    isLoading: true,
    menuId: 0
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logger = new LoggerService();
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    let projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.getProjectList()
      .then(res => {
        let projectList = new ProjectListModel();
        projectList.data = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ projectList: projectList,
                        isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.logger.error(error);
      });
  }

  ChangeSlide = (menuId) => {
   this.setState({
      menuId //Here you will receive which slide to show and according to that render slides in mySliderbar component
   })
  }



  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <MySidebar ChangeSlide={this.ChangeSlide} />
          <ProjectSliderComponent menuId={this.state.menuId} projectListId={this.state.projectList}></ProjectSliderComponent>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

In mySlidebar

```
import React from "react";
import './MySidebar.scss';
import {slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

export class MySidebar extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


 changeSlide = (e) => {
   console.log("Clicked " + e.currentTarget.id); //get text content of
   this.props.changeSlide(e.currentTarget.id)
 }


  render() {


    return (
        <Menu customCrossIcon={false}>
            <button onClick={((e) => this.changeSlide(e))} className ="menu-item" id="Project1">Project 1</button>
      <button onClick={((e) => this.changeSlide(e))} className ="menu-item" id="Project2">Project 2</button>
        </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

In slider component, you have to listen when the new props are coming and according to that change the slide see componentWillReceiveProps

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import './project-carousel.component.css';
import { ProjectComponent } from '../project/project.component';
import { LoggerService } from '../../services/logger-service';
import { appConfig } from '../../config';

export class ProjectSliderComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    activeSlide: 0,
    timestamp: Date.now()
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logger = new LoggerService();

    this.settings = {
      dots: appConfig.dots,
      arrows: false,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      infinite: appConfig.infinite,
      speed: appConfig.speed,
      autoplay: appConfig.autoplay,
      autoplaySpeed: appConfig.autoplaySpeed,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      mobileFirst: true,
      className: 'heliosSlide',
      beforeChange: (current, next) => {
        this.setState({ activeSlide: next, timestamp: Date.now() }); 
      }
    };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(nextprops.menuId != this.props.menuId){
    this.slider.slickGoTo(nextprops.menuId, true)//use slider instance to 
    //call the function to go to a particular slide.
   }
  }


  render() {

    let i = 0;
    const { menuId } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
      <Slider initialSlide={menuId} ref = {c => (this.slider = c)} {...this.settings}>
        {
          this.props.projectListId.data.map(projectId =>
              <ProjectComponent key={projectId} id={projectId} time={this.state.timestamp} originalIndex={ i++ } currentIndex = {this.state.activeSlide}></ProjectComponent>)
        }
      </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. I'm missing the last piece, that is how I tell the slider to go to slide x. I can correctly get the value of the button clicked in App.js, but how can I change slide inside ProjectComponent?

Comment: Please have a look at the new answer. In that you will see the instance of slider is calling slickGoTo function.

Answer (score 2):

At the react-slick docs you can read about [slickGoTo](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#slickGoTo), which is a method of the `Slider` component.

Since you're already storing `this.slider` you can try to make it accessible in `MySidebar` and use it whenever `changeSlide` is called. Most likely you have to create a `changeSlide` method on top level and hand it as property to your components.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. When you say "make it accessible in MySidebar", what do you mean? I mean, how can you make it accessible?

Comment: The most react way to make something accessible in a child component is to hand it as property. So either you want to hand the object/variable itself or a callback to trigger something in the parent component.